# Magento XML configuration

Tags: xml, magento

I have follow instruction as per magento U, configuration XML. but XML configuration is not working from my side.

Here is code which i have done.

**app/etc/First_Module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <config>
        <modules>
            <First_Module>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </First_Module>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

in local codePool

**First/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <default>
        <some>
            <ranadom>
                <xpath>Here is value</xpath>
            </ranadom>
        </some>
    </default>
</config>
```

Now, I want to call xpath value in cmsController indexAction()

For that I have put code in **cms/contollers/indexAction()**

```
 echo "test";
 echo Mage::getStoreConfig('some/random/xpath');
 die;
```

With help of echo Mage::getStoreConfig('some/random/xpath'); i am call value of xpath Tag.

when my cms indexAction() will call at that time. I can see Here is value.

Can any one tell where i am wrong?

Comment: in config.xml you use 'ranadom' but then call the config value using 'random'.  Just a typo?

Comment: Thank you  Jonathan Hussey, In my config.xml you have a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config.xml you have a typo. You wrote `<ranadom>` instead of `<random>`.

Answer (score 1):

- Your `config.xml` code just saves the default value of `some/ranadom/path` xpath and it doesn't insert the value in database. Please check in your database table `core_config_data` if you have the row with path `some/ranadom/path`. If you don't have, create a `system.xml` file and put the declaration of `some/ranadom/path` xpath there, it will make insert to your `core_config_data` table.
- Put your module declaration in your `config.xml` file.
- You are getting the value by `Mage::getStoreConfig('some/RANDOM/xpath');`, while in your `config.xml` it's `RANADOM`
- Did you clear the cache to reflect these changes?

Comment: Sorry I havent gone through the complete question

Answer (score 0):

Go to system->cache management and check all items and disabled them. Then you need not flush your cache every time and you get the output dynamically just refreshing the web page.